# How To Automate Workflow in Sharepoint 2013 so that I don't have to manually run the workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow

Someone had mentioned that I would need to use SharePoint PowerShell for windows to do this. I don't know the steps.

This is for SharePoint 2013. Also, does the builtin 3-point workflow eliminate the need to do further work? I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: By automate what do you mean? Run a WF when an item is created/edited or at some time during the day (such as for an email reminder workflow?)

Comment: @Roland I mean when an item is created. In this case, I have a list of contracts with their expiration date in a Document Library. I have a column for contract expiration date. My WF is to trigger an alert email 90 days from the expiration date and ask for follow up steps. I created the WF but when I executed, it doesn't work. I have to manually check each line from the Document Library and then run the WF to make it work. Thoughts?

Comment: Manually check each line (I assume you mean document..?). For a test create a new list library with a workflow set to start on create and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger the workflow automatically, whenever item is added or edited then in the list settings >> Workflow setting >> select the workflow
there is an option to enable this.

[image: Graphic from workflow settings page]

Comment: not sure which option to check off? I am using Sharepoint 2013 (enterprise) and my Start Options include:

1. Allow this workflow to be manually started by an authenticated user with Edit item permission (checked)

2. Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item (NOT CHECKED)

3. Creating a new item will start this workflow (CHECKED)

4. Changing an item will start this workflow (CHECKED)